# Special void-compatibility rule java8 lambda

Tags: java, java-8

I am not able to understand this topic. Please share some good example

```
Predicate<String> p = (String s) -> list.add(s);
```

Where we can you this predicate.

```
Predicate<String> p = (String s) -> list.add(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

`list.add(s)` always returns `true`, so this `Predicate<String>` is pointless.

If you ignore the side effect of adding the `String` to `list`, you can replace it with:

```
Predicate<String> p = s -> true;
```

It can be used if you rely on the side effect, but that's usually not a good practice.